# How do I get the configuration of another node in Nvidia Isaac?

Tags: nvidia-isaac

https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/doc/doc/component_api.html#isaac-map-map states:

> This component is used to mark a node as a map and gives convenient access to the various map layers and also some cross-layer functionality.

But it is not documented anywhere how to do that. In my case, I just want to know the defined `waypoints` in the `WaypointMapLayer`.

How do I do this specifically and in general? The documentation seems to be really missing a lot of such details or examples still.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, mostly through existing header files in the SDK, I found my way up through `Codelet`, `Component::Node`, to `Application`. The `Application` class has methods for finding arbitrary nodes in the application graph, specifically one can use:

```c++
getNodeByName(const std::string& name) const;
```

In my case, I was able to call this in my components `start` method:

```c++
// get the map node:
isaac::alice::Node* map = node()->app()->getNodeByName("map");
// within that node, get the WaypointMapLayer component:
isaac::map::WaypointMapLayer* comp = map->getComponent<isaac::map::WaypointMapLayer>();
// get the configuration parameter we want:
waypoints = comp->get_waypoints();
```